# Jquery Slides, i want one open at all times

Tags: java, jquery, css, jquery-animate

So i am trying to make this kinds "slideshow" using jquery slides.  i have it right now so that the images slide when i hover, but i would like to have one of the images always expanded if the user is not hovering over an image.

Here's a link to the test page http://www.johnnyedick.com/indexSlideUpTop.html if you want a live view.

and here is the jquery i am using:

```
$(function() {

                $('#box1').hover(function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({ "width" : "530px"}, 1000);
                }, function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({ "width" : "100px"}, 1000);
                    });

                    $('#box2').hover(function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({ "width" : "530px"}, 1000);
                }, function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({ "width" : "100px"}, 1000);
                    });

                    $('#box3').hover(function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({ "width" : "530px"}, 1000);
                }, function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({ "width" : "100px"}, 1000);
                    });
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: i am not sure about your problem. but you should defenitely apply a Class to those divs, and trigger for the class instead of each id ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a simple function: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/9NVWt/2/. Probably it will be useful. I believe it can be further perfected by someone more experienced in jQuery, I'm just a novice in it

Comment: hey man thanks, this is along the lines of what i want.  I see if i can twerk it to fit mine

Comment: Great solution by @skip405 I've forked it and provided jsfiddle of your site and modified the above solution here http://jsfiddle.net/mgrcic/Jwg3t/ . I expands on mouse enter and doesn't contract on mouse leave and stays expanded on last slide with mouse enter.

Comment: @plurby, notice that in my jsfiddle I've got TWO functions: 1 - it consists of two parts: mouseenter and mouseleave; and 2 - animating the first `.box` back two 230px. You've copied half of the code)))

Comment: This one looks more like it. http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/Jwg3t/1/ The only thing that is missing - is the 530px width on pageload of the first box, But I can't see a mistake in css.

Comment: I've added the `id` selector in the css, though I don't like that - but it does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/Jwg3t/2/

Comment: @skip I know i copied only that i needed to achieve the functionality of expanding and leaving it expanded. I'm glad you forked my fiddle and provided a complete working sample. Nice solution.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you a bit, sorry) glad I could help

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, some very helpful comments and solutions.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

updated:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#box1, #box2, #box3').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ "width" : "530px"}, 1000)
            }, function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({ "width" : "100px"}, 1000);
                   }).mouseleave(function(){
                     jQuery.fx.off = true;
                         });
```

Comment: i'm getting some syntax error on line 5 of ur code, could the .mouseleave after the animate be doing this?

Comment: @117sparten yes, no its because of this `$(function() {` which should be     `$(function() { ... })` sry, i'll modify ma answer.

`

Comment: Ah, yeah i see what your code does, it talks to all my divs and expands them on hover. however it does not shrink them back on mouseoff. I just get one larger image after the other.

Comment: I do like the idea of just talk to them all at once..hmmm ill try to think of something to incorporate this and come with a solution

Comment: @117sparten Ok man, this sounds cool, good luck, can you make a jsfiddle for the markup http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: idk how to link my html file to the js file on jsfiddle, but the code is live here http://www.johnnyedick.com/indexSlideUpTop.html

Answer (score 0):

add this code , after the hover function code

```
$('#box3').css('width','530px') ;
```

when page coming 3rd div showing normal size